Camera movement in gta5
I'm working on automating a minigame in GTA using Python. Currently, I'm using the pydirectinput library, but I'm having trouble moving the camera within the game. When the code runs outside of GTA, my mouse moves correctly. However, inside the game, the mouse doesn't move properly. The mouse will randomly move 1 -3 times without me being able to figure out why.
Here's the code I'm using.
import pyautogui
import pynput

print("Starting")

pyautogui.sleep(8)

mouse = pynput.mouse.Controller()

mouse.move(120, 50)
print("Move 1")
pyautogui.sleep(1)
mouse.move(120, 50)
print("Move 2")
pyautogui.sleep(1)
mouse.move(120, 50)
print("Move 3")
pyautogui.sleep(1)
mouse.move(120, 50)
print("Move 4")
pyautogui.sleep(1)
mouse.move(120, 50)
print("Move 5")
pyautogui.sleep(1)
mouse.move(120, 50)
print("Move 6")

Those looking to replicate my issue can do so by running the code while inside a gta online server with the mouse input method as Windows. It wont work at all if the input method is raw or Direct Input

Unforunately, pynput, pyautogui, and keyboard, among the other thousands of keyboard/mouse libraries out there, can have trouble navigating on certain apps. I'm guessing that GTA might have some blocker that prevents you from doing this. But anyway, there's a reason that it's blocked. My advice would be, Just play the game the way it was intended. :)
